# Remove all picture Metadata except for one

Tags: exiftool

I need to remove all metadata from the pictures in one folder, except for the date it was taken.

Is there a way to remove all metadata with an exception?

The current command I use is:

```
exiftool -all= *.jpg
```

I tried to read the man for exiftool but I'm still having trouble with the command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out finally:

```
exiftool -all= -tagsFromFile @ -*date* *.jpg
```

Comment: You can also use: -AllDates for the dates. 
You can use -P and -overwrite_original_in_place to preserve filesystem modification (+creation) date. 
`exiftool -P -all= -tagsFromFile @ -AllDates -overwrite_original_in_place *.jpg`